# hover not working in span

Tags: html, css

In my code. I am displaying title in anchor `<a>` tag and author name inside anchor in span tag. I write code for hover on anchor tag when hover on span it is working fine , but when hover on `<a>` it is only change hover effect on anchor tag and not change color for span.

HTML :-

```
<a href "#" class="link">
This is my link title 
<span class="span-text">Author Name</span>
</a>
```

Css :-

```
span {
 color: #ccc;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover, span:hover {
 color:#9A1A4A;
}
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roop1886/2cEYc/1/)

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/2cEYc/2/ ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use instead

```
a:hover, a:hover span {
    color: #9A1A4A;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ySu3w/

Comment: +1 and accept :) .Yes I am also waiting for 5 minute because it was not allowed to accept me

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan The answer was so simple but question confused me. huh! It happens some times....

Answer (score 0):

`!important` is *yuck*, and not needed here.

```
a:hover, a:hover span {
 color:#9A1A4A;
}
```

Comment: [That was related to another answer that’s been deleted in the meantime.]

Answer (score 0):

please try this

http://jsfiddle.net/roop1886/2cEYc/

**css :**

```
span {
 color: #ccc;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}


 a:hover, a:hover span {
    color:#9A1A4A;
}
```